# How do you say ‘auto-antonym’ in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

Neither Benson, nor Wells, nor Vikivortaro, nor ReVo, nor Sonja has an entry for ‘[auto-antonym](http://www.cross-reference-kingdom.com/vorto-auto-antonym.html)’.

Perhaps it should be ‘aŭtoantonimo’, following the pattern of ‘aŭtodidakto’ / ‘aŭtokrato’.

Answer (score 3):

*Aŭto* is not a productive prefix in Esperanto - unless we're talking about automobiles. You'd use *mem-* in this situation.

***mem-antonimo***

Answer (score 0):

Bona vorto povus esti sin-malnomiga.